# CQWP to query specific list without GUID

Tags: 2007, content-query-web-part

I would like to use CQWP to query from one Specific list and that is something we can achieve using following Property and like this

" replace with
</Lists> ]]>"

This is good but if i export this from dev environment to other environment then this is not going to work as it list has different guid.

how to get around this please advise

Thanks
Ronak

Comment: Your xml seems to have gotten eaten by Html goblins.  Can you post it and surround it with the `code designator` - back quotes

Answer (score 2):

Remove the GUID based reference from the exported .webpart file
Use the ListUrl property and use a server relative Url to the list.

```
<property name="ListGuid" type="string" />
<property name="ListUrl" type="string">~sitecollection/Pages</property>
```

Comment: Thanks Gavin where do i need to do that in ListOverride Property ?

Comment: I don't have a 2007 environment handy, but when you export the CQWP there is should be properties for ListId and ListUrl, just use those.